# Не меняется размер TextView

Tags: android

Собственно размер шрифта меняется но остальные view не подвигаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class StackAdapter extends BaseAdapter...
...
public View getView...
final ViewHolder viewHolder;
...
viewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.telephone_1);
...
    viewHolder.layout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView)viewHolder.layout.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
                        textView.setText("din1");
                        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);

    //or
                        TextView textView2 = (TextView)viewHolder.layout.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
                        textView2.setText("din2");
                        textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
                        int height_in_pixels2 = textView2.getLineCount() * textView2.getLineHeight(); //approx height text
                        textView2.setHeight(height_in_pixels2);

                    }
                });
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/telephone_1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hello"
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hello"
                        android:id="@+id/textView22"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял это список? скорее всего надо менять размер convertView, так как размер textView меняется нормально

А вообще попробовал накидать простенький пример - размер элемента списка меняется нормально:

xml активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml элемента списка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

код адаптера

```
class StackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;

    public StackAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    .......        

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView.setText("din1");
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22 * (position + 1));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы правы. У меня тоже работает если добавлять на прямую в `getView`. Но я добавляю в отдельном потоке `layout.post(new Runnable()` в котором сначала узнаю `layout.getHeight` а потом уже добавлять в `layout` определенное количество элементов. Я этого не указал в примере т.к пока `layout.getHeight` неважен. Проблема в том что через `layout.post(new Runnable()` элементы не добавляются а изменяются крыво.

Comment: Попробуйте в своем `Runnable`, после установки размера шрифта вызывать `layout.invalidate()` или `layout.requestLayout()`

Comment: @BogdanShulga напишите полный код адаптера, я пока не понимаю зачем таким сложном образом менять размер шрифта

Comment: Пробовал `layout.invalidate()` не помогало

Answer (score 1):

Расчет высоты textView

```
int height_in_pixels = textView.getLineCount() * textVew.getLineHeight(); //approx height text
textView.setHeight(height_in_pixels);
```

---

Вы должны передавать единицы в которых нужно измерять размер шрифта. Рекомендуется для андроидов в SP.

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
```

---

Или через ресурсы

Создаем файл `res/values/dimensions.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="bigTextSize">22sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

В **activity** пишем следующее:

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.bigTextSize));
```

---

После поиска нашел такой вариант:

```
textView.setText("I am a Text", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Или после ресайза:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: переписал с учетом ваших замечаний. Но результат тот же

Comment: Дополнил. Попробуйте

Comment: Нет не работает. Я в это `layout` даже елемент добавить не могу. Могу изменять только имеющиеся объекты. И то видите как они меняются.

Comment: А xml этого `layout` есть? Можете привести?