# Есть способ узнать какой будет размер View без его создания?

Tags: android, view

Есть способы получить разрешение и плотность экрана. Но можно ли на основании данной информации рассчитать размеры `view` для конкретного `xml`?

То есть какую бы длину и ширину имел бы `view` при таком экране? Как бы создать незаметно макет. И вытянуть из него нужную инфу.

Comment: я задавал этот вопрос разработчикам андроид. Ответ краток - пока view не "рассчиталось" (а сделает это оно как раз в момент перед отображением), размеры лишены смысла. Какую задачу Вы решаете?

Comment: Какой вы шустрый на пару с разработчиками :) Похоже, что я решаю не решаемую задачу. Это я уже костыли ищу. К поломанному велосипеду. Если в кратце. То мне надо узнать высоту елемента и в зависимости от этого програмно добавить туда нужное количество `textview` елементов. Это просто сделать с обычными `view`. Но я юзаю стороннюю библиотеку и по какой-то причине после того как `view` из библиотеки отрисовался я не могу туда ничего нового добавить.

Comment: [Вопрос по проблеме 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736336/cant-change-size-of-textview) [Вопрос по проблеме 2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514916/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-textview)

Comment: можно библиотеку переписать:)

Comment: Если бы я хоть знал куда копать. И в ней ли проблема? Я уже автору написал. Буду надеятся что ответит.

Comment: Очень непонятный вопрос. Вам необходимо, перед тем как добавить элемент, узнать размеры другого и относительно его уже добавить другой View, с нужными размерами? Есть несколько способов, чтоб это сделать. Если вы уточните свой вопрос, я с радостью отвечу.

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли. Да есть [способы но они не работают](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514916/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-textview). Но в моем случае они не работают. :( У вас есть еще предлодения? С радостью выслушаю :)

Answer (score 1):

Плотность экрана

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Размеры экрана для api < 13

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()
```

Для api > 13

```
Point point = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
point.x;
point.y;
```

Comment: Сорри. Но это не совсем то что я спрашивал.